# I saw author/media$credit tag using list, is it possible multiple authors on same channel?

Tags: youtube-api

Example, http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/google/uploads?v=2&start-index=1&max-results=50&alt=json,

"author":[{"name":{"$t":"Google"},"uri":{"$t":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Google"},"yt$userId":{"$t":"K8sQmJBp8GCxrOtXWBpyEA"}}]

"media$credit":[{"$t":"google","role":"uploader","scheme":"urn:youtube","yt$display":"Google","yt$type":"partner"}]

Both **author** and **media$credit** tag is a list, so is it possible **index 1** on the list? If it's impossible, why **list**?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any scenario in which there would be multiple values returned for those fields. I can't say for certain why it's a list and not a single element.